# How to represent dependencies between horizons and uncertainty when forecasting multiple horizons?

Tags: time-series, correlation, forecasting, quantiles, univariate

Suppose the following case of univariate time series forecasting.

We forecast sales of a product 1 till 7 days ahead. The true distribution of the actual sales is the following: there is a 100% chance that there will be a sale of 30 on one of each 7 days, each day has a chance of 1/7 of being the day with the sale.

What kind of output should a forecasting algorithm give to predict such a distribution?

Quantile forecasting does not suffice. Each day has a chance of 1/7 of sale of 30 and 6/7 of 0. If we combine the distributions of each day and assume them to be independent, there would still be a chance of (6/7)^7 of having no sales, which is clearly not the true distribution.

How to represent dependencies between horizons and uncertainty when forecasting multiple horizons?

Comment: You should be forecasting based on a model which is based on a 'loss model' associated  with calling the wrong day and quantity sold. The predicted daily values which minimize this loss function should be your forecast.  You could also just generate random sets, subject to constraints, and see what produces 'acceptable results' if there is a problem defining the loss function.

Comment: The predicted daily values which minimize any loss function don't give information about the uncertainty nor about the dependency between the forecast of different days ahead.

Comment: Note, one can expand the simulation to examine different  and  multiple horizons, based on observed historical data.

Comment: When you build a simulation model, the examination of the historical 'goodness-of-fit'' can produce an estimate of 'uncertainty'.  You define the latter. Dependency follows from constraints on simulated value. Relationships between multiple horizons can also be examined based upon provided relevant relationships built into the simulation logic.

Comment: What I am talking about is classically performed in econometric forecasting.  The latter requires a deep understanding of the inter-relationships between variables. If you have some other path that foregoes this base of knowledge, best of luck. Remember garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: But I don't want to assume a certain model structure, I want to use a machine learning method, which gives an output that represents the distribution of the 7 days I want to forecast, including the dependencies between horizons.